# Access "Paste Options" without disabling "Quick Analysis"

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, copy-paste, feature-regression

At my work, we just upgraded from Office 2010 to Office 2013, and Excel has a new feature called "Quick Analysis". The feature looks pretty cool, and while I'm looking forward to playing with it later, right now I notice that it interferes with another feature I've grown accustomed to: the "Paste Options" popup that appears after you paste something (it's still there in Word and Outlook, so I know it wasn't removed from Office 2013). I know I could use the ribbon command to explicitly choose a paste format *before* pasting, but certain repeatable processes I follow are much faster with the aid of keyboard commands, which include sequences like `CTRL-V, CTRL, V` to Paste Values, or `CTRL-V, CTRL, W` to retain source column widths, etc. But now, the Quick Analysis popup appears in the place where the Paste Options popup used to appear, when I paste data. A Google search turned up [this post](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-excel/when-i-paste-in-excel-2013-i-get-the-quick/3d6169fb-3209-430e-8b10-663d563e6eaa) on Microsoft Answers, advising another user to disable the Quick Analysis feature to recover the Paste Options popup, but that seems like a pretty big throwaway.

Is there a way I can keep the old Paste Options popup, but still be able to use Quick Analysis, e.g., via its CTRL-Q keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it turns out that going into the Options menu, then disabling and immediately re-enabling the Paste Options setting fixed it; now when I paste, I get the Paste Options control initially. If I want to access the Quick Analysis feature, I can just click anywhere, then turn around and reselect the range, and Quick Analysis will appear just below the Paste Options. The CTRL key now opens Paste Options like I wanted.

Comment: This worked for me in Office 365 Excel. Very strange. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the *Advanced* options, select to *Show Paste Options*:

[image: Advanced options]